# Efficiently updating equations on Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a question regarding how I can speed up some of my calculations. I have several functions which can only be called from an inline cell equation (thanks to the design of the AddIn I am using for these functions).

I am designing a VBA which will involve repeatedly updating these equations on several different Worksheets. I have accomplished this simply by doing `Sheet("Sheet1").Calculate` for every sheet that needs updating. Now this works, *but it is slow* for my purpose (think: updating equations thousands of times). I understand that going back and forth between VBA and the Application is a resource drain, so what recommendations would you advise to make this run faster?

I have addressed the usual suggestions including setting `Application.{EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating}` to be false (the sheet also always persists manual equations).

As for the reason why I can't run these functions from my AddIn in VBA, the source code requires the cell reference for the caller. I am also trying to come up with some ways to trick this mechanism, but to little avail. Using `Application.Evaluate(...)` works functionally, but offers the poor performance of requiring to use the Application.

Any help, comments or suggestions on this (rather vague and open-ended) question is massively appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: If your core process involves running those calculations thousands of times then it's difficult to suggest how to improve that, other than looking at how your sheet is laid out and making sure it's as efficient as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. The sheet is cut pretty slim as it is. Is there anyway to save time with `.Calculate` ? I figure it is slower to repeatedly calculate sheets one after another -- can I select multiple sheets at once and calculate them together? (Something like 'Application.Calculate`, less the scope of all open worksheets)

Comment: There's `Range.Calculate`, `Worksheet.Calculate` and `Application.Calculate`  You might be able to union a range across worksheets and use the Range.Calculate method